# C# Entity Framework - Allowing only one record to have a boolean value of true in a certain column

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, boolean

I have a question that does sound a bit vague.

What is the best way to implement in C# using the Entity Framework a way of ensuring that for a certain column in the table only one record is allowed to be set to the boolean value of true.

This boolean value is displayed via a checkbox on a winform. I also want that when a user checks the value on the form, that record has its value set to true and every other record in the db now has that value set as false (so only one record at a time can ever have that particular column as being set to true)

Apologies if this sounds incredibly vague - and just a basic overview of how I need to implement this would be fine.

Many thanks.

Comment: implementing this logic using EF is expensive. Consider using Update statement or a database trigger.

Comment: It is much easier and less error-prone to store the (1) key of the selected row in another master-table. That translates to a singleton holding a SelectedItem ref in your model.

Comment: Redesign your database, remove the essentially wasted column and store the key of the special row in one row in another table. Less redunancy and data and greater performance come for free.